# AngularJS routing links don't work on reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I've been doing a mini project using the **TMDb API and AngularJS.** My Angular routing part works, and i can load the movie details on click. The click on the homepage takes you to **details** view and the URL changes to `movie/:id/:title` and now if the user clicks on another movie present in the **details** view, the relevant data for the newly clicked movie replaces the previous data. Now if i try going back using the browser the data of the previous movie is not loading up, but the URL shows the previous movie's title.

Along with this error, there's an other bug. When i try reloading the browser it causes **404 Error**. If i turn `html5Mode(true)`this occurs. If i disabled `html5Mode` the page doesn't show relevant information, but shows me an empty template in the view. I'm just a beginner in AngularJS. I don't know how to fix this.  I have mentioned the domain where i've hosted the website. I guess, looking at it would be easier to understand my  problem. Hope someone out here could help me.

**PROJECT URL:** http://movie-buffs.xyz/

This is my routing code.

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                templateUrl:'templates/movies.html'
            })
            .when('/movies/:id/:title',{
                templateUrl:'templates/moviedetails.html'
            })
            .when('/search',{
                templateUrl:'templates/search.html'
            })
            .when('/tv',{
                templateUrl:'templates/tv.html'
            })
            .when('/tv/:id/:title',{
                templateUrl:'templates/tvdetails.html'
            })
            .when('/celebs',{
                templateUrl:'templates/celebs.html'
            })
            .when('/celebs/:id/:name',{
                templateUrl:'templates/celebsdetails.html'
            })
            .when('/contact',{
                templateUrl:'contact_us.html'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:'/'
            });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

angularjs provides html5Mode, which makes your app use pushstate-based URL instead of hashtags. However this requires server side support, since the generated urls need to be rendered properly as well.

Simply copy index.html to 404.html, and add this to your app:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Please find [this](https://coderwall.com/p/kfomwa/angularjs-html5mode-on-github-pages) link for more information

**Solution 2**

open index.html page and in head section add

```
<base href="/">
```

Your Angular code enable `html5Mode`

```
 angular.module('main', []).config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {  
      ...
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      ...
    });
```

After doing this, you need to create a .htaccess file on the root of your shared **Apache server** as your are using apache server add below code

**Apache Server**

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

**IIS Server**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

That's it

Comment: I have added that code. Can you help me out with the views not loading problem? :)

Comment: did you copy your index.html code to 404.html? just copy that page to 404 page and that's all it'll work

Comment: I don't have 404.html page setup, so it goes to my webhost's link (Hostinger). Check out the URL i attached to the question.

Comment: Ohh than just create one page called 404.html and add that in your angular routing `otherwise({templateUrl:'/404.html'});` something like this way and than check

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I fixed the 404 error. Only thing left is the views not loading up according to Url

Comment: from this side i only can see that `moviesLoaded` in ng-view is hidden and image path is not proper you have to take a look at these points

Comment: one more solution i have found are you using iis server to host your app? if yes than please find [this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1191/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-page-not-found-solution) link it would be better solution as per my point of view

Comment: Oops, forgot to remove that bit, it was not supposed to be there. Even if i remove that i'm still gonna get an empty template with no data in it  http://movie-buffs.xyz/tv/67136/This%20Is%20Us   Like this.. Only if the ng-click part is done, the data loads up dynamically. But when i reload the page data is lost. How do i fix this? You've been very helpful, thanks a lot!!

Comment: No I'm not using IIS server. So, according to the solution from that link, I should make a web.config file in the root folder and add that snippet? Or should i install IIS?

Comment: No you don't need IIS you just add above snipet in .htaccess  file

Comment: Please mark as answer for future references as well

Comment: I'm a newbie at Stackoverflow, they expect me to have a minimum 15 points to mark this as answer. I'll do it as soon as i get the rep points

Comment: You need 15 Rep for upvote answer you can marked as answer even if you have not more than 15 points please find this link [how to marked as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Done :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Nice page! Try out the html5 mode answer from Curiousdev. And I think you can make the routing simpler. You could change the routing from

```
('/movies/:id/:title')
```

to

```
('/movies/:id')
```

Here is an example on single movie on imdb:

> http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219827/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2896364242&pf_rd_r=0QKNGNCGK3XM4PBDN2A0&pf_rd_s=hero&pf_rd_t=15061&pf_rd_i=homepage&ref_=hm_hp_cap_pri_2

They don't provide the title in the url either

Further: If you want to break down the problems in angular routing , remove all extra jquery scripts an so on. Make sure it works before you add the cool gui stuff

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. :) Even if i change the URL for routing I'm not gonna get the movie result relevent to the URL.   http://movie-buffs.xyz/movies/207703/Kingsman:%20The%20Secret%20Service  This link loads up empty view.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. In my config.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ( $routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});}]);
```

I divide the html with corresponding js in to folders ex:

```
/movie-details/movie-detail.html
/movie-details/movie-detail.js
```

My movie-details.js should look something like:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp')
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/movies/:Id', {
            templateUrl: 'movie-details/movie-detail.html',
            controller: 'MovieDetails as vm'
        });
    }])
    .controller('MovieDetails', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.movieId= $routeParams.Id;

    });
```

In the html you wont need any Controller directive. Just:

```
{{vm.something}}
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks for the help

Comment: This way you will keep the routing together with the html and js. Hopefully this will make it easier for the site to grow. Your problems might be because the controller is not loaded when the route hits. Maybe...

Comment: I have fixed all the bugs I had, Thanks a lot for your help. :)